# How to force parameter expansion of $ variable within result of `grep` to pass to another command

Tags: grep, path, xargs

I have a shell script that passes the content of a `.env` file with `grep`

```bsh
export $(grep -v '^#' .env | xargs)
```

In `.env` there's:

```bsh
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$PWD
```

however, if I run the command, the `$` variable expansion does not take place.

```bsh
$ echo $PYTHONPATH
$PYTHONPATH:$PWD
```

How do I force `$` variable expansion before it's exported?

Comment: `$PATH` isn't anywhere in your value. Did you mean `$PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: @I0b0 I was just trying to generalize `$` but didn't know how to and ended up with `$PATH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way to get such a file into the current context is to [source](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Sourcing) it: `. ./.env`. For the vast majority of cases this is equivalent to copy/pasting the code into your script and running it.

Comment: You might also need to do `set -a` or something to make these variables exported